# Ionic native-audio doesn't work on android

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic2

I'm having a problem to use the native-audio cordova plugin with ionic. I installed native using npm

```
sudo npm install --save @ionic-native/native-audio
```

And added a new provider called smartAudio (code attached below).
It works like a charm both in ionic's web view and on iOS emulator/real device as well.. but for some reason there's no sound on android emulators/real devices at all.

I have an ion-slides element that generate images slide using *ngFor, like this -

```
<ion-slides (ionSlideDidChange)="muteAnimalSound()" pager dir="rtl" [loop]="true" >
  <ion-slide *ngFor="let slide of animals_slides; let i = index" style="background-color: white">
    <img src="{{slide.img_url}}" (click)="playAnimalSound($event)">
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
```

Where playAnimalSound() function looks like this -

```
playAnimalSound(ev) {
    let animalSound = this.getAnimalBySource(ev.target.src);
    let currentIndex = this.slides.getActiveIndex();

    this.smartAudio.preload(currentIndex, animalSound[0].sound_url);
    this.smartAudio.play(currentIndex);
  }
```

My smartAudio provider was is defined like this -

```
export class SmartAudio {

    audioType: string = 'html5';
    sounds: any = [];

    constructor(public nativeAudio: NativeAudio, platform: Platform) {

        if(platform.is('cordova')){
            this.audioType = 'native';
        }
        //testing atlassian sourcetree

    }

    preload(key, asset) {

        if(this.audioType === 'html5'){

            let audio = {
                key: key,
                asset: asset,
                type: 'html5'
            };

            this.sounds.push(audio);

        } else {

            this.nativeAudio.preloadSimple(key, asset);

            let audio = {
                key: key,
                asset: key,
                type: 'native'
            };

            this.sounds.push(audio);
        }       

    }

    play(key){

        let audio = this.sounds.find((sound) => {
            return sound.key === key;
        });

        if(audio.type === 'html5'){

            let audioAsset = new Audio(audio.asset);
            audioAsset.play();

        } else {

            this.nativeAudio.play(audio.asset).then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
            }, (err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });

        }

    }
    stop(key)
    {
        let audio = this.sounds.find((sound) => {
            return sound.key === key;
        });

         if(audio.type === 'html5'){

            let audioAsset = new Audio(audio.asset);
            audioAsset.play();

        } else {

            this.nativeAudio.stop(audio.asset).then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
            }, (err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Could you provide the version info native media plugin?

Comment: We are seeing the exact same problem.  Even when not using `native-audio`, but plain HTML5 audio, it works in browser but not device.

Comment: @Gandhi - `@ionic-native/native-audio": "^3.14.0"`

Comment: @GonrasKarols Android webview is known to have problems wirh html5 audio/video tags. This issue could be due to path issue. What's the path you are getting in your code before invoking play?

Comment: @Gandhi I don't know how to check exactly the path before invoking play, but I use relative paths - for example: `{ name: 'cat', img_url: './assets/img/animals/cat.jpg', sound_url: './assets/sounds/animals/cat.wav' }`, When a user clicks on the right animal - Its' sound should play (from assets/sounds/animals folder)

Comment: Does it throw an error or warning or anything?

Comment: @GonrasKarols Could you just trying this simple app and see whether its working - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_Media Jus to isolate whether the issue is in device or ionic?

Comment: Can you try `setTimeout(()=>{ 
      this.smartAudio.play(currentIndex);
 },3000);` this once?

Comment: And i hope you did this `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-nativeaudio`? You didn't mention it.

Comment: @SwapnilPatwa - yes, of course i added the plugin (: And the setTimeout line of yours still doesn't work for me.

Comment: @GabrielBarreto - Where can i see errors/warnings while emulating an ios/android device using cordova?

Comment: Did you try on other device?

Comment: @SwapnilPatwa , yup.. tried on 3 devices and 2 emulators.

Comment: "@ionic-native/native-audio": "3.12.1" try changing version at package.json

Comment: Did you try device remote debugging with chrome devTool? Any error?

Comment: @GonrasKarols i usualy use Chrome DevTools's inspect device to debug my apps for cordova plugin errors

Comment: Were you able to solve it ? I'm having the same issue ( iOS - works, Android - not )

Comment: @RickyLevi unfortunately not.. still stuck with this one.

Comment: Did you solved it guys? Same problem....

Answer (score 1):

i found an issue in your smartAudio provider.
Please change *"asset: key"* to *"asset: asset"* and try again.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem.. and makes it not to work on iOS as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. But I found this article:
[Sound Effects using HTML5 and Native Audio in Ionic](https://www.joshmorony.com/sound-effects-using-html5-and-native-audio-in-ionic/)

I did everything as in this article - and I got a sound in my Android phone. Try it - it should work. Just in case, I will show the file package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.3.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-audio": "^4.3.0",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^4.3.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.3.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.3.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.7.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.4.3",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.0.0",
    "typescript": "2.3.4"
  },
```

The latest version of Ionic is used. This example works in the article. Try it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you repost this in English?  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange

Comment: @GonrasKarols:
The main reason why did not work for me
command: this.smartAudio.preload ()

it is necessary to place here:

`platform.ready (). then (() => {

       smartAudio.preload ('tabSwitch', 'assets / audio / clickSound.mp3');
 
     });`
not earlier and not later

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Android API levels are 14 - 21.

In older versions might not work.